# Internet speed over WiFi spotty

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

so I've got AT&T 300mbps routed into the basement which hooks into two UniFi APs which are installed on the first and second floor. The WiFi signal is strong and has no problems. I've also got two network data drops in two rooms which I connect to with no speed or performance problems.

The problems come from devices connecting over the WiFi network, like our phones, tablets and laptops. The speed constantly slows to a crawl or loses connection.

I've downloaded a WiFi analyzer app and here are the results.

<sup>click any image for full size</sup> 
[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot 2] [image: Screenshot 3] [image: Screenshot 4]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In places where there are a high number of WiFi AP's, changing which channels your network operates on can help.

Below you can see that channels 100-144 in the US are nulled, this is to reduce interference from Terminal Doppler Weather Radar (TDWR).([Source](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12720/cannot-use-5ghz-band-wi-fi-from-channels-100-140))

[image]

https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/how-change-wi-fi-channel-3325316/

Comment: So do I change the channel on the Access Point or the device (laptop, phone, etc)?

Comment: @Kevin it will be on the router itself. You'll want to pick a channel that is less used by other AP's around you.

Comment: ok currently it's set to Auto - I assume picking a specific one is probably better? if I just pick a random channel, will all the devices pick it up automatically?

Comment: @Kevin Definitely changed it to a specified one. If you look at your screenshot 3 and 4, for both your 2.4 and 5ghz channels yours overlap with a lot of other ones. you want to set your channel to one that is either not being used by other nearby routers or being used by few other routers

Comment: @Kevin http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html is a great tool for windows to see the channels of all nearby APs

Comment: I'd definitely move the 5GHz to two different bands, well away from each other, the 2.4 (is there only one??) looks best where it is. BTW, you need to repeat these tests from the problem locations, just to make sure.

Comment: @lost_admin  ok I'm changing the channels right now and then will test

Comment: @Kevin Good luck! Also, i have found that even though 2.4 is generally rated for up to 600mb/s, 5ghz works significantly better. Worth a shot as well

Comment: @lost_admin I changed it to 161 but there are still a number of devices in that range (I'll send screenshot) - I want to change it to the 100-144 range but the settings don't have that range

Comment: @lost_admin Ok, here's three different screenshots:

https://imgur.com/a/hGQsTXx

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't know I could put the 5GHz on two seperate channels

Comment: @Kevin You can use one of the lower band channels as well(36-48). Im going to edit my answer with a table that shows the channels, bands and FCC frequencies. Basically the reason you cant see 100-144 is because those are reserved by the FCC due to their interference with Radar equipment.

Comment: presumably this is controlled separately from each wifi extender/AP's user interface. I don't use Ubiquity devices myself but I understand them to be high-spec so I'd expect a high degree of control over them.

Comment: @lost_admin That's super helpful thanks - interesting about the Radar equipment as well ! I've moved both to two separate channels, so we'll see how that works

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, I have set them up in two different channels so they won't collide and I'll run around the house and test!

Comment: @Kevin Of course! I hope it does help out. Definitely interesting to look at how much overlap there is in everyday things!

Comment: @lost_admin I also downloaded that program you recommended which is pretty cool. I wonder if I can paste a log here

Comment: @Kevin Love the program, its great being able to sort the view specifically by channel usage. Makes it quite easy to look at!